# How to disable a button when switching Screens? (Android LibGDX)

Tags: android, input, libgdx

My render method:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    int w = GateRunner.WIDTH;
    int h = GateRunner.HEIGHT;

    cam.update();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, w, h);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    game.batch.begin();

    game.batch.draw(title_background, 0, 0, GateRunner.WIDTH, GateRunner.HEIGHT);
    game.batch.draw(title, (w / 2) - (w / 2), h / 2 + h * 12 / 90, w, (int) (w * 0.5));

    playButtonSprite.setPosition((w / 2) - (w / 2), h / 2 + h / 20);
    playButtonSprite.setSize(w, (int) (w * (144.0 / 1080)));
    playButtonSprite.draw(game.batch);

    game.batch.draw(instructions_button, (w/2) - (w/2), h/2 + h/20 - h*3/40, w, (int) (w * (144.0 / 1080)));
    game.batch.draw(about_button, (w / 2) - (w / 2), h / 2 + h/20 - 2*h*3/40, w, (int)(w*(144.0/1080)));

    game.batch.end();
}
```

My touchDown method.

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    float pointerX = InputTransform.getCursorToModelX(windowWidth, screenX);
    float pointerY = InputTransform.getCursorToModelY(windowHeight, screenY);

    if(playButtonSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(pointerX, pointerY)) //Play button
    {
        game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }

    return true;
}
```

I wanted to make it so when I clicked the Play "button", which is just a Sprite, it would move to PlayScreen. I did this by checking if the rectangle where the Play sprite was clicked. However, even though this part works, whenever I click in that rectangle area in PlayScreen, it runs the code again - it starts the PlayScreen over. How can I fix this?

Edit: also, there might be a better name for this question, so feel free to suggest.

Comment: Does it switch to a different screen from the one the button is on?

Comment: It seems your touchDown always checks if you just touched withing playButtonSprite boundary. You want to set up boolean flag and check it in your if condition. Additionaly I would advise to rethink your design because you got the same InputProcessor on both screens apparently (hence the problem).

Comment: @MikeMatusiak I actually don't take input on my second screen (there really isn't much on it yet". How should I redo my resign?

Comment: @TobLoef Well, the button is supposed to switch to a different screen from the one the button is on. When I click it in the new screen however, it still registers, which restarts the same screen. Basically, the screen doesn't change, but it restarts.

Comment: @4everPixelated Is the button visible, or does it happen when you click where it used to be? It sounds weird to me, I would very much like to see your whole code.

Comment: @4everPixelated I would have to see more of your class design etc. to be able to help you with it. What class is your touchDown implemented in, and how it is related to the screen classes?

Answer (score 3):

This is happenning because when you change screen, you still have the same input processor in place which is checking whether that rectangle of the screen is tapped. Whether the button is visible or not is irrelevant.

You can do one of these to fix it...

- Make each screen have its own input processor specific to its needs - this is the preferred option
- Have a single input processor that checks what the current screen is before handling actions

Alternatively, look into frameworks like scene2d.ui to handle this sort of stuff for you.

Comment: I second this. An input processor for each screen is the way to go. Also, if you continue to use libGDX you will almost certainly at some point have to learn Scene2D UI, so you might as well get it over with.